# How can I get an array of numbers through a form in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need the user to type an array of numbers through an input. But doing so just returns the array as a string to me. I wish I could somehow convert a string to an array of numbers, but I don't know how.

Component.html:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
  <div class="bg-white rounded-1 p-3" style="width: fit-content">
    <label for="array" class="form-label">INTRODUCE LA LISTA DE NUMEROS</label>
    <form [formGroup]="arrayForm" (ngSubmit)="enviarArray()">
      <input
        type="text"
        formControlName="userArray"
        id="array"
        class="form-control"
        aria-describedby="array"
        style="font-size: 35px"
      />
      <div class="text-center m-2">
        <button
          type="submit"
          class="btn btn-dark"
          style="width: 150px; height: 70px; font-size: 40px"
          [disabled]=""
        >
          Ordenar
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ArrayService } from 'src/app/services/array.service';
import { Array } from 'src/app/models/Array';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  providers: [ArrayService],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  arrayForm: FormGroup;
  newArray: [] = []
  constructor(
    private arrayService: ArrayService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.arrayForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      userArray: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {}

  enviarArray(){
    console.log(this.arrayForm.value)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You can use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert an array of string to an array of numbers

```
JSON.parse(text)
```

> But be sure to handle exception. If the string that you pass is not valid JSON then it will throw `SyntaxError`

**2)** Then, you can check whether the parsed data is an array or not using [Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const button = document.querySelector("button");

button.addEventListener("click", e => {
  const text = input.value;
  let arrayOfNumber;
  try {
    arrayOfNumber = JSON.parse(text);
    if (Array.isArray(arrayOfNumber)) {
      console.log("This is valid array: ")
      console.log(arrayOfNumber);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Wrong Array");
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" id="">
<button>convert</button>
```